# EmguCV 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' Exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exception, opencv, emgucv, typeinitializeexception

I have installed EmguCV 2.4.2.1777. I have a 32-bit windows 7 so I installed it using the installer. Now I am trying to write a simple code to capture a webcam's video in a window in C#. 
The problem is after during execution I am getting the following famous error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll 
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
```

The file Emgu.CV.dll is present in the folder. I don't understand why its giving that error.
I tried all the checks which are suggested by fellow stackoverflow users and also many other references:

1) Installed MSVCR:  MSVCRT 10.0 SP1 x86

2) copied the OpenCV dlls to the execution directory

3) I also have a 32-bit OS. So that also should'nt be an issue.

But when I checked for dependencies, I faced a problem:

I used DependecyWalker to open cvextern.dll and found the following dependencies missing:

```
NVCUDA.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-0.DLL
DCOMP.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
```

It also gave the following:

Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

Please help me out with the exception. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I copied all the dll files from C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-gpu 2.4.9.1847\bin\x86 to a folder called includes in my project and updated the "Copy To Output Directory" Option for these DLLs to "Copy Always" and it got rid of this issue.